# (revised)-Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a special tridiagonal matrix (nonsymmetric)?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

I need to consider to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following tridiagonal matrix, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & \beta          \\
\alpha & \gamma & \beta \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ 
& & \alpha & \gamma & \beta \\
& &  & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}_{m\times m},\quad~~m\in\mathcal{N}^{+},
\end{equation}
where $\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha = -\frac{1 + \gamma}{2}$ and $\beta = \frac{1 - \gamma}{2}$. I want to find some analytical form of these eiganvalues and eigenvector. But I have no idea about such problem. I remember that if $A(m,m-1) = \alpha,~A(m,m) = \gamma$, the problem will be easy to find the answer. 
Are there some ideas about this problem?

Comment: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But there is only the case for symmetric Toeplitz matrix. Maybe, we split the matrix into $A  = tridiag(-\beta,1,\alpha) + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0\\ &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\ && 0 & 0 &0 \\ &&& -1 + \beta& 0 \end{bmatrix} $, then we try to consider the eigenvalues?

Comment: Oh, look at the $-1$ at the bottom! Didn't see that. Sorry, no idea how to do that.

Comment: The second matrix in your previous comment is rank one and can be written as $(-1+\beta)uv^T$ where $u=(0,0,ldots,0,1)^T$ and $v=(0,0,\ldots,1,0)^T$. Hence $A$ is a rank-one update of $tridiag(-\beta,1,\alpha)$. This case should be pretty well-studied in the literature; for instance, one can use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to relate the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $tridiag(-\beta,1,\alpha)$.